# What causes a type error when subscribing to list?

Tags: python, typeerror, python-typing

I have the following code im running in CoLab with Python Version 3.8 (not 3.9):

```
from typing import List, Dict

def get_embedding(text: str, model: str=EMBEDDING_MODEL) -> list[float]:
    result = openai.Embedding.create(
      model=model,
      input=text
    )
    return result["data"][0]["embedding"]

def compute_doc_embeddings(df: pd.DataFrame) -> dict[tuple[str, str], list[float]]:
    """
    Create an embedding for each row in the dataframe using the OpenAI Embeddings API.
    
    Return a dictionary that maps between each embedding vector and the index of the row that it corresponds to.
    """
    return {
        idx: get_embedding(r.content) for idx, r in df.iterrows()
    }
```

Which results in this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-bd6d3a14202c> in <module>
      1 from typing import List, Dict
      2 
----> 3 def get_embedding(text: str, model: str=EMBEDDING_MODEL) -> list[float]:
      4     result = openai.Embedding.create(
      5       model=model,

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there a workaround to fixing the declaration besides upgrading to 3.9?

Comment: You have already imported `List` but are not using it. Use it.

Comment: @flakes: Uh, that answer is wrong; `from __future__ import annotations` solves a different problem. It happens to *mask* the problem in this case, but it's not actually solving the underlying issue.